# Chess Opening Document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, chess

I am trying to make a PDF with Chess Openings. Before I used skak but now I am converting it to texmate. I want to put the mainline in bold as centered text. I also want the diagrams centered. At this moment I sometimes get an incorrect move numbering when I put text between 2 parts of the notation. Another thing is that the enumeration is not an itemised list.

I tried to follow the manual that comes with the package but I must do something wrong. Can somebody put me in the right direction?

I include my 'main' text and the first 'chapter'.

```
\documentclass[dutch,twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[skaknew]{chessfss}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\topmargin =-15.mm
\oddsidemargin =0.mm
\evensidemargin =0.mm
\headheight =0.mm
\headsep =0.mm
\textheight =250.mm
\textwidth =165.mm
\parindent =0.mm

\setlist{noitemsep}

\newcommand{\nieuwelijn}[3]{
  \begin{center}\hrule\end{center}
  \newgame
  \section{#1}
  \position[{#2}]{#3}
}
\newcommand{\opening}[1]{
  \chapter{#1}
  \newgame
}
\newcommand{\printbord}{
  \begin{center}\showboard\end{center}
}
\newcommand{\sublijn}[3]{
  \begin{center}\hrule width 3cm\end{center}
  \newgame
  \subsection{#1}
  \newgame
  \position[{#2}]{#3}
}
\newcommand{\tekst}[1]{
  \parskip=2.mm
  #1
  \parskip=0.mm
}

\newcommand{\subsublijn}[3]{
  \begin{center}\hrule width 2cm\end{center}
  \newgame
  \subsubsection{#1}
  \newgame
  \position[{#2}]{#3}
}
\newcommand{\extra}[2]{
  \begin{center}\hrule width 3cm\end{center}
  \newgame
  \position[{#1}]{#2}
}
\newcommand{\variant}[1]{
  \begin{center}\hrule\end{center}
  \newgame
}

%\rightdiagramturn
\setboardfontsize{14pt}

\renewcommand\afterb{ }
\renewcommand\iopen{\par}
\renewcommand\iclose{\par}

\hypersetup{
citecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
pdfauthor={Marco de Booij},
pdftitle={Opening Theorie},
pdfsubject={Opening Theorie},
pdfkeywords={schaken, theorie, openingen},
pdfcreator={LaTeX with hyperref package},
pdfproducer={latex + bibtex + dvips + ps2pdf}}

\title{Opening Theorie}
\author{Marco de Booij}
\date{\today{}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\input{Engels.tex}

\end{document}
```

The content of Engels.tex is:

```
\opening{Engels - A10-A39}
\tekst{Het Engels dankt zijn naam de Engelse (officieuze) wereldkampioen Howard Staunton. Hij speelde het in 1843 tijdens zijn match tegen Saint-Amant en in Londen tijdens het eerste internationale toernooi in 1851.}
\begin{center}|c4|\end{center}
\printbord
\begin{center}|c5|\end{center}
\tekst{Het Symetrisch Engels heeft als voordeel dat hoewel er veel mogelijke zetten zijn dat je meestal op dezelfde stellingen en mogelijkheden uitkomt. Ook is de strategie zowel voor wit als voor zwart te gebruiken. Verder kan het ook gebruikt worden tegen het Réti.}
\begin{center}|Nc3 Nc6|\end{center}
\printbord
\tekst{Het hoofddoel is om als wit \wmove{d4} te spelen of als zwart \bmove{d5}.

Wit moet nu een keuze maken. Hij kan proberen om d5 te controleren of om \wmove{d4} te spelen. Voor de 1\textsuperscript{e} keuze speelt hij \wmove{Nc3} gevolgd door \wmove{g3} en \wmove{Bg2}. Voor de 2\textsuperscript{e} speelt hij \wmove{Nf3} waarna \wmove{d4} gespeeld kan worden of nog wat wachten en eerst nog wat verder ontwikkelen}
\printbord
\tekst{Nu is het zwart zijn beurt om een(zelfde) keuze te maken.}
\[|\ahead\begin{variations}
\var d4
\var Nf3
\var g3
\end{variations}|\]

\nieuwelijn{Tweepaardensysteem (Axx)}{w 3}{r1bqkbnr/pp2pppp/2n5/2p5/2P5/2N5/PP2PPPP/R1BQKBNR}
\begin{center}|d4|\end{center}
\printbord
\tekst{Wit speelt meteen \wmove{d4}.}

\nieuwelijn{Driepaardensysteem (A35)}{w 3}{r1bqkbnr/pp2pppp/2n5/2p5/2P5/2N5/PP2PPPP/R1BQKBNR}
\begin{center}|Nf3 g6|\end{center}
\printbord

\nieuwelijn{Fianchettovariant (A36)}{w 3}{r1bqkbnr/pp2pppp/2n5/2p5/2P5/2N5/PP2PPPP/R1BQKBNR}
\begin{center}|g3|\end{center}
\printbord
\begin{center}|g6 4.Bg2 Bg7 5.Nf3 Nf6 6.O-O O-O|\end{center}
\printbord
```

Comment: Your code is much to long. And due to the graphic it doesn't compile directly on other systems. Try to make a shorter self contained example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I removed the line with the graphic. You should now be able to tun it. I do not think that I can meke it shorter without the risk that the result is not like it should be.

Comment: Sorry, to debug the code one has to shorten the code to isolate the problem. Your example contains a lot of things obviously unnecessary like text, bibliography etc. It's  your task to remove them.

Comment: I removed the bibliography part. I do not know if the other things are unnecessary. It all might be the cause of the problem but I 'need' them in other chapters. This is only 1 chapter. There will follow more. I just want to know where/if my idea is wrong. The rightdiagramturn for example is in comment because it generates an error. Why? I do not know. It might be the wrong place. The documentation on texmate is complex to me and I have not been able to find much examples.

Comment: Well you may not *know* what is necessary to show the problem but you are a chess player, you should be able to analyze a position and so find out. So copy your document in some test folder and start by removing text from the end and from the comments. Remove the titles, remove hyperref and other packages and commands in your preamble. At each step control if the problem persists. When you have a small example come back.

Comment: This simple text: \begin{center}|c4|\end{center} \printbord \begin{center}|c5|\end{center} gives already the error that c5 is not a white move. I do not understand this. There is no \newgame defined between the 2 moves so I do not understand why they are both considered as white's first move. I analysed and tried different things but I cannot get this error away AND have the output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I want to post the 'correct' Engels.tex:

```
\opening{Engels - A10-A39}
\tekst{Het Engels dankt zijn naam de Engelse (officieuze) wereldkampioen Howard Staunton. Hij speelde het in 1843 tijdens zijn match tegen Saint-Amant en in Londen tijdens het eerste internationale toernooi in 1851.}
\par\centering|c4|\par\justifying
\printbord
\par\centering|c5|\par\justifying
\tekst{Het Symetrisch Engels heeft als voordeel dat hoewel er veel mogelijke zetten zijn dat je meestal op dezelfde stellingen en mogelijkheden uitkomt. Ook is de strategie zowel voor wit als voor zwart te gebruiken. Verder kan het ook gebruikt worden tegen het Réti.}
\par\centering|Nc3 Nc6|\par\justifying
\printbord
\tekst{Het hoofddoel is om als wit \wmove{d4} te spelen of als zwart \bmove{d5}.

Wit moet nu een keuze maken. Hij kan proberen om d5 te controleren of om \wmove{d4} te spelen. Voor de 1\textsuperscript{e} keuze speelt hij \wmove{Nc3} gevolgd door \wmove{g3} en \wmove{Bg2}. Voor de 2\textsuperscript{e} speelt hij \wmove{Nf3} waarna \wmove{d4} gespeeld kan worden of nog wat wachten en eerst nog wat verder ontwikkelen}
\printbord
\tekst{Nu is het zwart zijn beurt om een(zelfde) keuze te maken.}
|\[\ahead\begin{variations}
\var d4
\var Nf3
\var g3
\end{variations}\]|

\nieuwelijn{Tweepaardensysteem (Axx)}{w 3}{r1bqkbnr/pp2pppp/2n5/2p5/2P5/2N5/PP2PPPP/R1BQKBNR}
\par\centering|d4|\par\justifying
\printbord
\tekst{Wit speelt meteen \wmove{d4}.}

\nieuwelijn{Driepaardensysteem (A35)}{w 3}{r1bqkbnr/pp2pppp/2n5/2p5/2P5/2N5/PP2PPPP/R1BQKBNR}
\par\centering|Nf3 g6|\par\justifying
\printbord

\nieuwelijn{Fianchettovariant (A36)}{w 3}{r1bqkbnr/pp2pppp/2n5/2p5/2P5/2N5/PP2PPPP/R1BQKBNR}
\par\centering|g3|\par\justifying
\printbord
\par\centering|g6 Bg2 Bg7 Nf3 Nf6 O-O O-O|\par\justifying
\printbord
```

The mainline is in bold and centered. Also the numbering of the moves is correct and the variations are in an itemised list.

Do not forget to add the \usepackage{ragged2e} in the 'main' text. If not the \justifying will generate an error.

Comment: Your main.tex lacks \usepackage{ragged2e}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you might be able to use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=true}
%\usepackage[display]{texpower}
\usepackage{chessfss}

\margins{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}
\screensize{4.5in}{6in}
\backgroundcolor{lightgray}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\newlength{\symsize}\setlength{\symsize}{24pt}
\newlength{\boardwidth}\setlength{\boardwidth}{8\symsize}
\setboardfontsize{\symsize}

\newcommand{\board}[1]{\framebox{\parbox{\boardwidth}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\symsize}#1}}}
\newcommand{\row}[1]{\parbox[c][\symsize]{\symsize}{\hfill{#1}}}
\newcommand{\col}[1]{\parbox[b]{\symsize}{\hfil{#1}}}
\newcommand{\chessboard}[1]{\begin{tabular}{cc}
\parbox{\symsize}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\symsize}
\row{8} \row{7} \row{6} \row{5} \row{4} \row{3} \row{2} \row{1}}&\board{#1}\\
\row{ } &\mbox{\col{a}\col{b}\col{c}\col{d}\col{e}\col{f}\col{g}\col{h}}
\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}

\begin{document}\large

\BlackRookOnWhite\BlackKnightOnBlack\BlackBishopOnWhite\BlackQueenOnBlack\BlackKingOnWhite\BlackBishopOnBlack\BlackKnightOnWhite\BlackRookOnBlack\\
\BlackPawnOnBlack\BlackPawnOnWhite\BlackPawnOnBlack\BlackPawnOnWhite\BlackPawnOnBlack\BlackPawnOnWhite\BlackPawnOnBlack\BlackPawnOnWhite\\
\WhitePawnOnWhite\WhitePawnOnBlack\WhitePawnOnWhite\WhitePawnOnBlack\WhitePawnOnWhite\WhitePawnOnBlack\WhitePawnOnWhite\WhitePawnOnBlack\\
\WhiteRookOnBlack\WhiteKnightOnWhite\WhiteBishopOnBlack\WhiteQueenOnWhite\WhiteKingOnBlack\WhiteBishopOnWhite\WhiteKnightOnBlack\WhiteRookOnWhite\
\blue{\BlackQueenOnWhite\BlackKingOnBlack\WhiteKingOnWhite\WhiteQueenOnBlack}\
\newpage
\begin{center}\chessboard{
\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\\
\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\\
\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\\
\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\\
\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\\
\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\\
\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\\
\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare\BlackEmptySquare\WhiteEmptySquare
}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. Thanks for the effort. I will try to put an image at my question to show how I want it and show what is wrong.

Comment: No problem.  I just copied the work file I use to copy chess puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

texmate doesn't store the move counter globally. So skak loose track of the state of game if you surround parts of the game with a center environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[skaknew]{chessfss}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\storechessstate{%
 \if@white\global\whitetrue\else\global\@whitefalse\fi \global\move=\move}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
%Works
\newgame
|c4 c5 e4| 

|e5|

%Errors due to grouping
%\newgame
%\begin{center}|c4 c5 e4| \end{center}
%
%\begin{center}|e5|\end{center}

% Workarounds
% ==========

%\mainline works

\newgame
\begin{center}\mainline{1.c4 c5 2.e4}\end{center}

\begin{center}\mainline{2... e5}\end{center}



%Storing state works, but untested if it affects variations and comments
\newgame
\begin{center}|c4 c5 e4| \storechessstate \end{center}

\begin{center}|e5|\end{center}


%centering/justifying instead of centering environment works to:
\newgame

blbalbalbablabablabal

\par\centering
|c4 c5 e4|
\par\justifying %from ragged2e

blbalbalbabla

\par\centering
|e5|
\par\justifying 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try it tonight and let you know the result. I think that I will go for the last option.

Comment: It works as I want it to work. I will now concentrate myself on the itemised variation list.