# How to draw a chessboard with (\multido )?

Tags: chessboard, multido

[image]

How to draw a chessboard with (\multido )?

Comment: Welcome! Why not `foreach`? `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) grid (8,8);
 \fill foreach \X in {0,...,7}
 {foreach \Y in {0,...,7} 
 {\unless\ifodd\numexpr\X+\Y
  (\X,\Y) rectangle ++(1,1)
 \fi}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: i think with(\multido ) because the varying color depths of the
individual fields

Comment: Nothing to do with multido, but see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers/168304?r=SearchResults&s=1|48.0755#168304 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140324/chess-opening-document/140351?r=SearchResults&s=2|9.2634#140351

Comment: Anyone considering writing an answer: as far as I can see this might be a homework problem, and if you happen not to meet the requirements of a third party, in this case the instructor of the course, your answer may get unaccepted after having been accepted for a couple of days. The main problem is of course this stupid "accepting" (and "unaccepting") of an answer, but there is the additional problem that the requirements are not clear (as explained above), which is why I vote to close the question as "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 2):

The varying color is IMHO way easier to implement with `\foreach` than with `\multido`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,7}
 {\foreach \Y  in {0,...,7} 
 {\unless\ifodd\numexpr\X+\Y
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{20+8*\Y}
    \fill \unless\ifodd\Y [black!\Z!white] \fi (\X,\Y) rectangle ++(1,1);
 \fi}}
 \draw (0,0) grid (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here the color varies only if `\Y` is even and only along the `\Y` direction. This is controlled by the color fraction

```
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{20+8*\Y}
```

and the `\unless\ifodd\Y` statement. Of course, you can implement any variation by changing this.