# Drawing a chess queen in a Tikz grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, grids, chess

I'm quite new to LaTeX and I'm trying to replicate this using Tikz:

[image: Possible ways to place 4 queens on a 4 x 4 chessboard]

I know there is some chess-related things I can include, but it diesn't seems to be adapted for something like this.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[xstep=0.75cm,ystep=0.5,color=gray] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
inner sep=0pt,
anchor=south west,
nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.75cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}
]{
  & ♕ &   &    \\
  &   &    & ♕ \\
♕&   &    &    \\
  &   & ♕ &    \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

This is my best attempt while trying to reproduce it. However this yield an error because the unicode character of the queen is not included in the utf-8 inputenc I guess, and I couldn't find how to include a special character or a picture in a Tikz grid...

I am not english and I am new to this forum, so the post might contain few mistakes. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Let's break it down. First, you need to use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to declare that you are going to use the unicode character `♕` in your document. Say you map `♕` to a command `\KelkunQueen`. Then you want to define `KelkunQueen` to be a command that enters a tikzpicture and draws a queen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally found how to solve the problem after some additionnal searches on special characters.
For anyone who would have the same problem, the package `skak` seems to be perfect:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
 
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]{
  & \symqueen &   &   \\
  &   &   & \symqueen \\
\symqueen &   &   &   \\
  &   & \symqueen &  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

Thanks for the replies!

[image]

Comment: `\symqueen` is provided by the chessfss package (which is loaded by skak), so `\usepackage{chessfss}` will work too.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers/168304?r=SearchResults&s=1|50.3944#168304 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140324/chess-opening-document/140351?r=SearchResults&s=2|9.8705#140351