# Adding coordinates to a chess board picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have created the picture of a chess board (Japanese chess, indeed) and I would like to add coordinates that is arabic numbers (1, 2, ..., 9) on the upper board, and kanji numbers on the right side. So my questions are:

1. How can I add numbers on the top and on the side of the board?
2. How can I write kanji-numbers using latex?

This should be the final result:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a3paper,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, very thick]
        \foreach \w / \h / \r in {1.5 / 1.8 / 6pt} {
            \draw [line width=5pt] (current page.center)
            +(-9 * \w, -9 * \h) -- +(-9 * \w, 9 * \h) --
            +(9 * \w, 9 * \h) -- +(9 * \w, -9 * \h) -- cycle;
            \foreach \s in {-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7} {
                \draw (current page.center) +(\s * \w, -9 * \h) -- +(\s * \w, 9 * \h);
                \draw (current page.center) +(-9 * \w, \s * \h) -- +(9 * \w, \s * \h);
            }
            
            \foreach \y in {-3, 3}
            \foreach \x in {-3, 3} {
                \fill (current page.center) +(\x * \w, \y * \h) circle [radius=\r];
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Thank you Nickie. I've added your code to mine but side letter don't show. This is my new code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a3paper,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, very thick]
        \foreach \w / \h / \r in {1.5 / 1.8 / 6pt} {
            \draw [line width=5pt] (current page.center)
            +(-9 * \w, -9 * \h) -- +(-9 * \w, 9 * \h) --
            +(9 * \w, 9 * \h) -- +(9 * \w, -9 * \h) -- cycle;
            \foreach \s in {-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7} {
                \draw (current page.center) +(\s * \w, -9 * \h) -- +(\s * \w, 9 * \h);
                \draw (current page.center) +(-9 * \w, \s * \h) -- +(9 * \w, \s * \h);
            }
            
         \foreach \i / \c in {-8/9,-6/8,-4/7,-2/6,0/5,2/4,4/3,6/2,8/1} {
            \path (current page.center) +(\i * \w, 10 * \h) node {\Huge\c};
        }
        \foreach \i / \c in {-8/a,-6/b,-4/c,-2/d,0/e,2/f,4/g,6/h,8/i} {
            \path (current page.center) +(10 * \w, \i * \h) node {\Huge\c};
        }
        }
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might find this useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140324/chess-opening-document/140351?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C9.7388#140351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By adding these two loops at the end of your external `\foreach` loop's body:

```
    \foreach \i / \c in {-8/9,-6/8,-4/7,-2/6,0/5,2/4,4/3,6/2,8/1} {
      \path (current page.center) +(\i * \w, 10 * \h) node {\Huge\c};
    }
    \foreach \i / \c in {-8/a,-6/b,-4/c,-2/d,0/e,2/f,4/g,6/h,8/i} {
      \path (current page.center) +(10 * \w, \i * \h) node {\Huge\c};
    }
```

you will get something like:

[image: result]

2. To get your kanji numbers, replace the letters `a`-`i` with them (in UTF) and use `xelatex` (or the format of your choice) with a font that can display them.

Comment: Thank you Nickie. I've added your code to mine but side letter don't show. This is my new code:

Comment: The side letters don't show because your paper is too small. :-)
Change `{1.5 / 1.8 / 6pt}` to something like `{1.0 / 1.2 / 4pt}` and you'll see them.